# How does increment on a typecasted pointer work?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, postfix-operator

This code prints "world" how is it doing so can anybody explain?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char i =10;
        char *pc = (char*)&i;
        int *pi = (char*)&i;
        pi++ && pc++;
        if((void*)pi==(void*)pc)
            printf("hello");
        else
            printf("world")

    }
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic should be covered by any decent text book. You can learn this without asking for human intervention.

Comment: this code prints `world` http://ideone.com/032FQl

Comment: Note: you can cast any address to type `char` without violating *strict-aliasing* rules, but you cannot simply cast between other types in the same manner. Make sure you review and understand sections `6.5.6` and `6.5.7` of the C standard. (to the extent it is understandable, then look at the related posts here on *strict-aliasing*)

Answer (score 2):

To quote chapter §6.5.2.4, *Postfix increment and decrement operators* from `C11` standard, (*emphasis mine*)

> The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the **appropriate type is
>   added** to it). [...]

Now, in your case,

1. Initially, `pc` and `pi` points to the same address.
2. `pc` is a pointer to type `char`, whereas `pi` is a pointer to type `int`.

Next,

- After doing `pc++`, `pc` will get incremented by the size of the type, `char`. So,  `pc` points to a memory location which is same as `(char *)pc + sizeof(char)`
- after doing `pi++`,`pi` will get incremented by the size of the type, `int`. So, `pi` points to a memory location which is same as `(char *)pi + sizeof(int)`.

Now, `sizeof(char)` being 1 and considering `sizeof(int)` is 4/8 (32/64-bit platform), you can understand, the final pointers held by `pc` and `pi` will be different.

So, the `if` evaluates to false.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` can vary, but in any event, `sizeof(int)` will be greater than `1/sizeof(char)`, so the two pointers can not be equal after they are both incremented.

Comment: I get this but doesn't pi get typecasted  to char* and hence increment should be by 1 byte.

Comment: @SachIn `pi` doesn't get typecasted to anything. It's the `&i` which gets (_unnecessarily_) typecasted to `char*` and stored into `pi`. The type of `pi` has no effect whatsoever on the RHS _typecasting_.

Answer (score 0):

With pointer arithmetic, it is useful to think about how many bytes must the pointer move past to get past 1 full object that it points to.

An `int` pointer points to `int` objects. Moving an `int` pointer past 1 `int` object would require moving the pointer past all the bytes in that `int` object (which would be 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine).

Similarly, moving a pointer to some larger object past 1 such object will involve moving the pointer past all the bytes in *that* object.

Therefore, if you think about incrementing (or decrementing) a pointer as moving a pointer past (or before) an object (or objects), it is obvious that the pointer value (the address) must change by the number of bytes in that object.

In your example, both the pointers at first point to the same address in memory. Incrementing an `int` pointer moves it by the size of `int`, and incrementing a `char` pointer moves it by the size of `char`. Their values end up being different because each changes by a different value.